# Show workbench moderation comments on node view page

Tags: entities, display-suite, workbench

I use the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) modules suite: Users do change the state of content items (moderate) and can enter a comment about that change.

This status change history can be seen in the tab `node/node_id/moderation`.

I want to include that view at the bottom of every node view page.

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve that?  Maybe the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module is useful for that (it has some computational field stuff)?

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve this using [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) Module.

- Install [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module
- Create a new field of type `computed`
- In the field settings, On the Computed code (PHP)

  `$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->log;`
- Now in manage display make this computed field visible. That's it.

Note: *This is just one way of achieving it.*

Instead of installing any modules, You can also **write tpl file** for the particular content type and display the log message.